# Certain Edm.Int32 and Edm.DateTimeOffset Column are showing null values in Azure Search

Tags: azure, null, azure-cognitive-search

I uploaded some records to azure search, but when tried to search the data in the portal, it is showing null values.

```
 "Date":"2000-10-29T00:00:33.000Z" (Edm.DateTimeOffset)
 ,"Year":2000 (Edm.Int32)
 ,"Month":10  (Edm.Int32)
```

**In the Azure Search Results,**

> "Date":null
>      ,"Year":null
>     ,"Month":null

Sometimes the Edm.String is also returning null values. What I have done wrong?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you made those fields `retrievable` in the index definition? If so, we (I work on the Azure Search team) can take a closer look if you let us know your service and index names.

Comment: Yes I made those fields as retrievable only.

Comment: OK please let us know your service name and index name. You can find me at eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to upload the document through API,is working. It is showing all the Values in the search result.

Comment: In order for us to investigate in more details, we'd need to know your service and index name. Please contact me with those details.